# program compiled when function parameter does not match the const parameter declaration in c

Tags: c, function, constants

I have a piece of code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(const int x, const int y);

int main()
{
    printf("%d", add(9, 8));

    return 0;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

I forward declared the function "add" with const parameters after that i defined it without the const parameter, and when i compile it the compiler gives no complain.
The out put of the program is: 17. Why does this happen ?

Comment: MSVC says *warning C4028: formal parameter 1 different from declaration* and for parameter 2. Turn up the warnings level?

Comment: Did you compile this with all the warnings on?

Comment: I compile it with gcc -Wall -o test test.c, nothing comes up

Comment: Certainly in C++, const qualifiers are removed from the top-level type of function parameters - I'm looking for some reference to the same being true in C ...

Comment: With -pedantic? Perhps gcc sees you haven't modified anything.

Comment: This is call-by-value. You are putting information that can not possibly be a part of the prototype in your prototype. I think it's reasonable to ignore, as are parameter names. Try `const int *`.

Comment: I compiled it with the -pedantic flag and still nothing

Comment: What do you mean by that ? @Neil

Comment: What I mean is it's not a part of your prototype whether the parameter is `const` or not; it will be erased anyway. It's only important in the function block itself. So it gets ignored. _Eg_, `int a(const int foo);` is the same as `int a(int);`.

Comment: Oh okay i see, thanks.

Comment: Otoh, if you have a pointer, `int a(const int *)` is not the same as `int a(int *)`. This is the same `int a(int *const)` and `int a(int *)`.

Comment: If anything the reverse makes some sense.  _Declare_ `int add(int x, int y);` and _define_ with `int add(const int x, const int y) { ...}`.  The `const` serves no purpose in the declaration and without it, reduces clutter.  As part of the definition, its useful to assure the values do not changes in the following code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the function declaration and function definition have to be [compatible](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7), we all know that. So the same name and same return type and type of parameters. So we know from [C11 6.7.6.3p15](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15):

> For two function types to be compatible, [...] corresponding parameters shall have compatible types. [...]

But, there is an explicit backdoor, later in that text:

> (In the determination of type compatibility [...] each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

The [*type-qualifier*](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3) is for example `const`. And it is ignored. You can put any type-qualifier and it is just ignored when checking if the function declarations are the same with each other.

```
int func(int n);
int func(volatile int n);
int func(const int n);
int func(const volatile int n);
int func(int n) {
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So MSVC produces an irrelevant warning?

Comment: @tstanisl I don't think the warning is irrelevant. Even if the behavior is well defined by the standard, a difference between declaration and definition is at least suspicious and *may* be unintentional. (The programmer might have forgotten to add the qualifyer in the definition.)